How do I remove the "Created with" note on Instagram posts?
Is there a quick way to remove the note on my Instagram posts that shows that the photo was created using Ray-Ban Meta?

The photo shows "Mit Ray-Ban | Meta erstellt", which is German for "Created with Ray-Ban | Meta".
Is there a setting in Instagram that disables showing this note? The post was created on iOS using the Instagram app.
I assume I can remove all the meta-information from the photo, or more specifically, "Make" and "Model" from the EXIF data. Is there a way to do this on Instagram?

Please [edit] your question to provide more details about this.  Provide an English picture as this site is English only. Your glasses eco system is an Android & IOS only and I assume the post was done using a mobile app. You need to explain how you posted the image to Instagram and that will likely inform why you are seeing the tagging.

Thank you for the feedback @Blindspots. The description shows a translation of the tag text in English. I have also added a note that this post was created on iOS using the Instagram app. However, I assume that this tagging is related to the photo meta-data and unrelated to how the Instagram post was created.

Why do you assume that? My understanding is that IOS and Android have specific apps from Meta for integrating with the Meta Rayban. Seems plausible that it would leave a trail. You could verify this independently by disassociating a photo from your mobile device (eg email it to your desktop) then upload it from your desktop using the standard web app and see if there is a difference. You could also include a link to a raw image in your post so we can take a look at it using photo tools and see what our own experience is uploading.

As it stands this is a very niche product targeted at mobile ecosystem. We don't  know what  you are actually doing nor where the info is coming from, can't currently troubleshoot it based on the info you have shared, and the introduction of foreign language content only serves to obfuscate the issue further. If you can troubleshoot it yourself, or share the info and files required for us to do it for you that would be useful.

@Blindspots My assumption is based on a few things that come together here: the EXIF data contains the information on the camera make/model and it's easy for Instagram to use this information to advertise Ray-Ban Meta when rendering the post, independently of the app used to upload the image. There is no reason to add this logic to the Instagram App on Android/iOS, as it would introduce unnecessary technical difficulties and privacy concerns.

Regarding the "don't know what" I am "actually doing": I have taken a photo on a Ray-ban Meta and used it in an Instagram post. I think there are no additional requirements to reproduce this problem. Also, I don't think calling this a "very niche product" does not help in finding a solution. If there is someone here who had a similar problem it would be great if they could share their experiences. I will try to provide additional information, but I really do not think the matter is this complicated.

Focus on adding in the requested information and a sample raw file if you still need help solving this. Your assumptions & your concern about characterizing the product as niche, are counterproductive.  With ~300k+ units sold and only ~30k in use the user-base is very small, and further reduced for users capable of helping you, then reduced again as they must be part of this forum that's unrelated to the product or mobile apps it integrates with. You have better odds of winning the lottery. I suggest you cater your post to the audience.

@Blindspots This is a different product: your link refers to Ray-Ban Stories. Ray-Ban Meta were released in October 2023. There are no current numbers about the units sold. Anyways, I did not want to discuss your definition of "niche", but wanted to point out that this comment does not help improve the question. Same thing with the lottery comparison. Thank you for your feedback and taking the time to answer. I have understood your point and will try to provide additional information, as mentioned in my previous comment.
